# Can't retrieve boolean value from Shared Preferences Android

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences

I am trying to retrieve boolean from `SharedPreferences` but boolean is always on false. 
The code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
    boolean crosshairIsShown;
...
prefs = getSharedPreferences("Weapon1", MODE_PRIVATE);
crosshairIsShown = prefs.getBoolean("crosshairIsShown", false);
crosshair();
..
crosshair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (crosshairIsShown == false) {
                    crosshairIsShown = true;
                    crosshair1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    crosshair2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    crosshair.setImageResource(R.drawable.crosshair_enabled);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("crosshairIsShown", true);
                    editor.commit();
                } else {
                    crosshairIsShown = false;
                    crosshair1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    crosshair2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    crosshair.setImageResource(R.drawable.crosshair_disabled);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("crosshairIsShown", false);
                    editor.commit();
                }

            }
        });
...
private void crosshair() {
        if (crosshairIsShown == false) {
            crosshair1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            crosshair2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            crosshair.setImageResource(R.drawable.crosshair_enabled);

        } else {
            crosshair1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            crosshair2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            crosshair.setImageResource(R.drawable.crosshair_disabled);
        }

    }
```

Why is this happening? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Don't know if it is the reason but your logic in crosshair (better name: setCrosshair) and onClick is reversed. Better also: call setCrosshair in onClick instead of coding everything again.

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Method:

```
@Override
public boolean getBooleanValuesFromPreferences(String key) {
    boolean data = getPreferences().getBoolean(key, false);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this turned out to be an obvious thing, but I fail to see how is this different from the OP's way. Could you please explain more about this?

Comment: why is that better? Why is the OPs code not working?

Comment: it will directly return you your key that is stored in shared preference.

Comment: like this String YOUR_KEY = "yourstoredkey";

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't want to be too picky here, but I don't see how this answers my questions... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use getBoolean for this pas "key" and "false"

boolean flag = getPreferences().getBoolean(key, false);

Comment: why is that better? Why is the OPs code not working?